# How can I Make accurate progressbar result indication when I have value more then 100

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have Loop whose range is from 0 to 100000  , I want to show it's accurate progress in progress bar , but I have problem my progressbar runs even after completing 100% progress so how can I make actual progress indication when I make loop even 100000 times

My code In python pyqt5:-

```
  bar.setMinimum(0)
  bar.setMaximum(100)

  for i in range(0,100000):
         ### Here is my function that perform my process and delay for 1 
         ## second
         bar.setValue(i)
```

Comment: How did you initialize the progress bar?

Comment: I have initialize my progressbar just by setting minimum value as = 0 and maximum value as 100

Comment: Why don't you show us the code for that?

Comment: Tasks that take more than 33 ms (is an approx) are blocking for a GUI so they should not run in the GUI thread, if they run as it is in your case generate undesired effects such as not updating the GUI, you have to run it in another thread.

Comment: SO How can I solve this?

Comment: @Programminghub Check the answers to the questions below the title of your question, there you will find the solution.

Comment: @eyllanesc what is Selenium?